# Import of Dash module alters .csv files

Tags: python, plotly

I've run into a strange behaviour when using the Dash library and I apologies in advance as I don't think I can't make an example which is easy to reproduce, so instead I will include all the information I think is relevant.

I was trying to create a small dashboard which loaded some data and then plotted it in a bar chart. The code I used for this is below (it is adapted from the Docs):

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import os.path as path


def find_unique_id(data, first_name, second_name, season):

    name = first_name + '_' + second_name
    data_filt = data[data['season'] == season]
    data_filt = data_filt[data_filt['name'] == name]
    print(data_filt['unique_id'])

    return data_filt['unique_id'].iloc[0]

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

# assume you have a "long-form" data frame
# see https://plotly.com/python/px-arguments/ for more options

path_data = path.join(path.dirname(path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))), 'Processed', 'player_database.csv')

data = pd.read_csv(path_data)

unique_id = []
unique_id.append(find_unique_id(data, 'Harry', 'Kane', 2020))
unique_id.append(find_unique_id(data, 'Mohamed', 'Salah', 2020))
unique_id.append(find_unique_id(data, 'Heung-Min', 'Son', 2020))

fig = px.bar(data[data['unique_id'].isin(unique_id)], x="round", y="points_mean3", color="name", barmode="group")

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

    html.Div(children='''
        Dash: A web application framework for Python.
    '''),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure=fig
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

The player_database.csv is loaded and detailed in the picture (notice the file sizes):

[image]

However now whenever I import any Dash related module even in a different file, it changes all the files in this folder, and appears to role them back to an earlier state. For example when I run the following code, you can see the change in file size happening:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.express as px
```

This alters all the files in this directory (again as shown by the file size):

[image]

Does anyone know why this might be happening, has Dash got some kind of cache somewhere which loads the files it was working with from some previous state? I've tried googling and can't find anything on this.

Thanks

Comment: As a first step, I would start removing code line by line until I find the lines that make the file sizes change. After you've done that, maybe you have answered the question yourself.

Comment: Thanks np8, apologies I probably wasn't clear, yes that is what I did and found that it was the import statements for dash. By simply importing the dash modules , without anything else in the file would cause the file sizes to change. The final code snipped with the four import statements will cause the files to change.

Comment: Which one of the four imports changes the file sizes?

Comment: So any of the dash related imports: import dash, import dash_core_components as dcc and import dash_html_components as html. However two other things I have just found out 1) If I move outside the working directory and import Dash, everything works fine, 2) if I delete the .csv files then when importing dash it throws an error stating it can't find the file. So somewhere dash is keeping a cache of the app which it is then trying to reload when I import dash in the working directory

Comment: Do you happen to have any `.py` files in your working/project directory? I had a problem once where `dash` imported my own script which ran some code and produced side effects.

Comment: Yes there are other .py file in the working directory. I will try deleting them and then import dash. Cheers

Comment: So this was the issue thanks, without this tip it would have taken me ages to find the issue. I had a script which I had called test.py which was being run as dash was imported ...... the test.py scrip did some filtering before resaving the DataFrames as the .csv files.

Comment: Now when you said, I remember that the problems were summoned by a `test.py` in the project root. I even filed an [issue](https://github.com/plotly/dash/issues/1339) about it to the dash GutHub page.